# How do you make it so a tables input column meant to update its row shares a submit button with the rest of the columns inputs?

Tags: html, css, input

So I’m basically trying to do the front end for a inventory sheet. For simplicity let’s just say it’s 3 Columns. First 2 columns will be In stock/ rented. Last column will be for me to either add or subtract. I don’t want to have to do this for every row(item). Is there a better way to have only one submit button at the bottom of the table? This is what I currently have for one row

```
<tr>
<td>
<form>
<input type=”number”>
<input type=“submit”>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see this will be many submit buttons that will have to update row by row. How can I simplify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function submits(){
const row1 = document.querySelectorAll(".row1");
const row2 = document.querySelectorAll(".row2");
for (let i = 0; i < row1.length; i++) {
  row1values=row1values+","+nodeList[i].value;
}
for (let i = 0; i < row2.length; i++) {
  row2values=row2values+","+nodeList[i].value;
}
}

function alerts(){
alert(allvalues)
}
var row1values = 0;
var row2values = 0;

//add onclick on submit at use event.preventDefault;

//The firsy coordinate will be 0,0

//you can join them lateer
```

For the first question using the colspan property in html5 will help.

The last line of code will be

```
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;background-color:blue;"><input type="button" onclick="submits()" value="Submit"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Hopefully, this helps! Ask still if this doesn't work for you!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? It's a bit confusing without it.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean by “it’s a form”. I am doing this inside a HTML TABLE.  I will be making multiple forms in each table row. Just don’t know how I could combine their submit button into one. Also I don’t see a colspan in documentation. Do you mean colgroup? Thank you for your answer by the way

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: The answer is js if it's fine to you. You can use other code to join them later. Let me know for any other help. I edited the answer.